# update shows Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lunar Release

Tags: apt, updates

I using Ubuntu 23.04. When I run `sudo apt update` it always shows the following error message.

```
Ign:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                                  
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                                     
Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.188.12 80]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What you've provided in pastes, is **not** a archive mirror, but used to hold specific 3rd party modules created by OEMs for specific hardware in conjunction with Canonical. They are **not** for standard use, but only specific packages for OEM hardware.